# ajax and json_encode() form validation error

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am able to display success and fail messages if the form has validation errors or not but I am not sure how to get the errors to display one under each other in this php code:

```
$errors = array();
    $response = array();

    if(empty($_POST['name'])) {

        $errors['name'] = "Name required";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $errors['email'] = "Email required";
    }

    $response['errors'] = $errors;

    if($errors) {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Fail";

    } else {

        $reponse['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

The line I need to change is probably:

```
$response['message'] = "Fail";
```

Comment: So I believe what you are saying is that all the errors are on the same line? If that is the case, a simple solution would be to add a new line after each message.

Comment: No, all this outputs now is FAIL when I submit the form and don't fill in the required fields. I use jQuery to output: $("#output").html(data.message);

Comment: Ah got ya. Yeah, each time you set `$response['message']` you override the previous value of it. You could make messages an array `$response['message'][] = 'some text'` then loop through them to display them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your issue, but if the goal is for the user to get the list of errors encountered, then everything you did was quite correct.

The errors are in

```
$response['errors']
```

so the json_encoded result of $response permits Javascript (client-side) to browse those errors as an array, and correctly print them.

You should not return HTML formatted text. It's the role of the View (client) to render the results, accordingly to CSS rules.

So I would say that there is nothing to change here. On success == false the client must print the errors from `{ 'errors' : { ... }}`

If you cannot/don't want to edit the client-side Javascript / rendering page, then you have to concatenate a string with `<br>` or a `<ul><li>` and provide this one in `$response['message']`. It's ugly, but whoever has constraints still has solutions.

Comment: So, you are saying I should use jquery to output the messages and not do it in the php code?

Comment: Absolutely. Minimize your results size, and perform all the tedious rendering on the client. This will make your back-end a hell-ton less coupled and maintainable.

Comment: I am no expert at jQuery but this isn't working so well:  `$( "#output" ).html(data.errors.name);
        $( "#output" ).append("<br/ >" + data.errors.email);`

Comment: Well, that is another question more Javascript orientated you have to post on Stackoverflow ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the error message as you detect it
    $errors = array();
        $response = array();

```
    if(empty($_POST['name'])) {

        $errors['name'] = "Name required";
       response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Name Required</div>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {

  $errors['email'] = "Email required";
 response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Email Required</div>";
    }

    $response['errors'] = $errors;

    if($errors) {

        $response['success'] = false;
       // $response['message'] = "Fail"; we added the message during the error detection

    } else {

        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I need the line you have commented out because I check for it in the jQuery:  `if(data.errors) {
        
       $( "#output" ).html(data.message);
       
       }`

Comment: can you show me you success function in ajax please

Comment: `if(data.success) {
      $( "#output" ).append(data.message);
       
      } else {
       
       if(data.errors) {
        
       $( "#output" ).html(data.message);
       
       }
      }`

Comment: As I see it there is no difference you added a "flag" error in the array, i added the message so in both cases the errors array is initialized. Give it a try.

Comment: I see your point. Nothing is returned when I do it your way. The success message also no longer displays if I fill in the form correctly

Comment: I think the concatenation is causing an issue. If I remove it then a message appears.

Comment: I know this isn't the best way to do it but it will do the work. So you just have to find a way to concatenate the message inside the email check.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps Arturo Andressi is correct and I should rather use jQuery to output the errors.